# What is the best job title for me?

Tags: title

I don't know what the most suitable job title would be for myself.

1. I'm the one hiring people for my team.
2. I do programming of hardware devices to make it .dll and continue innovations so that the frontend can use it to their software. I use C++/C#/Serial Port for the device. And I also make classes in Unity3d to support the API that I created.
3. I decide which OS, Hardware Device should be used for the machine for the compatibility of the programming language that will be used.
4. I'm the head of the team.
5. I do the planning for software development.
6. I make reports of the progress of the game software to the owner of the company.

Although I think the job title is not really important, I just want to know what would be a suitable job title based on my responsibilities.

Here are the list of job titles that I'm curious about:

- Head of Software Development
- Head, Platform Software Engineer

or please suggest other job titles that might be suitable for my responsibility.

Added: We develop Games Software.

Comment: I'm actually fairly curious, and although I don't have a definitive answer, I think you need to understand your roles and responsibility more clearly.

It seems as if you are both in a manager/team lead role as well as a Dev role. Are your primary duties managing or developing? If they are mostly one or the other you have your answer.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I think, its not. I'm expecting on part of Software Development position only.

Comment: @my_mistakes well the company is new, so basically we have multiple roles as of now. But they informed me to choose a suitable job title according to my job responsibilities right now.

Comment: Not a duplicate: linked discussion is about HOW to choose title - it does not even provide details about the work done.

Comment: @virolino Questions about specific job responsibilities and skill for one person's job are [off-topic here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/16983), because answers won't apply to anyone else who visits this site. We always change specific "what skills/what title should I have" questions to  "how do I decide", which would be a duplicate.

Comment: @grit one question - which may sound obscure - do you *think up the name of the product* (or have input to the name)?

Comment: @DavidK - not a big deal but I don't agree with what you're saying there (it seems irrelevant to this QA)

Comment: @Fattie If this question is closed and you disagree with the close reason, you are welcome to start a discussion on it in [meta].

Answer (score 2):

"One man orchestra" would fit best.

Beyond joke, there is no job title to cover simultaneously:

- programming in several completely different domains (drivers, Unity...);
- HW + SW architecture;
- hiring
- head of team
- planning and tracking
- reporting to the owner of the company.

You cover at least these titles (words may vary):

- Software Engineer
- System Architect
- Team Lead
- CxO ( am not sure what is the content of your reports: CEO, CFO, CIO, CTO...)
- (Software) Project Manager

NOTE: I do not know the details of the company, but you have too many responsibilities to be able to perform all of them properly and successfully, AND keep your general health - at the same time.

*Edited to add:* I met person(s) who said that they do everything, from cleaning the floors to CEO included. You can use that "title" as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm like that now. Because the company is new and at the same time, I'm their first employee who have the knowledge for their product and they informed me to hired people. I know that I'm doing more that one role, so right now, I just want to think which is more suitable or closest job title I'm doing right now, Because if software engineer, then Head of Software Development?

Comment: It seems that I was not very wrong. At this moment you practically have all the titles in the company, so my initial joke is the true answer :) However, you should decide what you want to do mid- and long term and depending on that, you can think of a title.

Comment: *"there is no job title to cover simultaneously..."* Nonsense, Viro - it's just the product lead.

Comment: "Product lead" is a management position. Writing code is an execution position. They require by definition at least 2 job titles. I found no literature until now to recommend mixing decision and execution responsibilities into the same person, about the same project. Basic knowledge of management science.

Comment: @virolino, you are right. that's my point of asking question here. To decide what I want to focus on the Mid and Long term. What position usually do Hardware Integration? is it Platform Software Engineer?

Comment: @Grit: I am not sure what you mean by "hardware integration". In different businesses it can mean different things. My kind advice is: do not get stuck in names. They are less relevant. From time to time they change anyway. I will tell you: my current job is quite mixed-up. I have different "job title" depending on where you look at it. When somebody asks about my position / title, I just raise my shoulders slightly and say "I guess I am project manager, but I am not sure". Different people use different titles. The effect on me? My night's sleep is sooo unaffected.

Comment: Just choose what you want to do and do it. That is what matters. I worked at a company where managers were is the sport of changing all names of everything (departments, groups, projects, titles) every year. Result: I stopped caring about the names altogether. When somebody asked me in which department I worked, I just explained our work. I never failed to transmit the correct information in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply

## Product lead

"I'm the one who also decide which OS, Hardware Device should be used for the machine"  "I'm also the person who make reports to the owner of the company." ..etc

you're the product lead.

It's very likely that you indeed also "invent" aspects of the product, I'm guessing.  So, you have ideas for the features and the nature of the product itself, you think up "inventions" to solve problems and so on.

Basically this "I was also informed that I'm the head of the team." is the "team lead", and then once you are actually forming the product ("choosing the hardware..." etc) you're the product lead.

By the way, this is how you make a *lot* of money.  Keep it up!

---

Note, you mention "platform" - indeed you could say **"platform lead"**, which is a bit corporate sounding.  In a smaller company, you're just the "product lead", plain and simple.  Enjoy!

---

And finally !  OP has mentioned wants to be a bit more circumspect than product lead.  I really think "platform lead" is a good choice.

- team lead (or simply "lead"). in a word you are "completely in charge of the software"
- platform lead.  like that but indeed you "decide everything" about the nature of the platforms, operating systems, etc
- product lead.  same as platform lead, but you are more pretentious, have ideas about the product itself, and you make more money!

It looks like

## Platform lead

is what OP wants here.

Comment: How about developing the software? because I need to help in programming to launch our first product.

Comment: @grit - for sure, the product lead is 10000% in charge of the software, and beyond to the hardware and "actual invention" of the product.  (with for example "team lead" you don't have to say "team lead .. software")

Comment: I'm sorry, I think its not. I don't invent/innovate product machine. I'm just telling which OS, Hardware are compatible with the software and programming language that will be using.

Comment: hi @grit !  Of course, "it's your life"  :)  I think you are "splitting hairs", based on all you have said I would just call you the product lead.   But maybe "platform lead" is more circumspect - excellent for you ?

Answer (score 0):

**Your job title is found in your contract.**

Titles are given by the employer, not picked by you unless you're in contract negotiations and apply for a certain role you have in mind.

**You're a team lead at best, as you were actually told.**

Head of anything usually refers to company or department wide with multiple teams or departments within your responsibility.

The smaller the company, the more phony and hollow that title becomes.

Comment: I was told I'm the head of the software developers.

Comment: @Grit   Well, then that is your title. If you want to make it official (as would be good to do), get it in writing(even if just an email) or, ideally amend your contract with your new responsibilities.

Comment: what is this position? is this a managerial position or a tech lead position?

Comment: @Grit both but you should clarify with your employer which responsibilities they expect you to fulfill if you're unsure.

Comment: "Your job title is found in your contract."  contracts rarely even mention a "title" (if he's a "contractor" - anyway).  often the paperwork with salaried positions doesn't even mention a "title", and it really sounds like he has "no title" the company is so small. (and I bet he has .. no paper contract!) I think DB it's perfectly reasonable to want to know the **"best way, in the industry, to describe what the role."**

Comment: @Fattie my contract is coming. That's why I was asked to think of my job title and responsibilities. That's why I'm here to known which is better.