# Team name change

Tags: team

We're 2 teams of ***SQL Server Database Administrators*** one based in *Europe* and one in *India*, apart from traditional DBA's work we work on different technologies also. we have been looking for team name change which suits our current work.

1. Europe team wants to have **Engineer** in the designation, for example: *System Engineers*, *Database Engineers*.
2. Indian team needs a name that gives significance to **Database** in the name and they also wants **Engineer** also in the name, for example: *Database Reliability Engineers*, *Cloud Engineers*.

   where as Europe team don't care if Database is in name or not.

Now coming to the other technologies we work on:

- **Azure**: We spin up VMs, Create PaaS DBs, Create ADF Pipelines, Manage Subscriptions, Manage permissions etc
- **Google Cloud**: Work on Big query, buckets, Spin up VMs, manage projects, manage permissions etc
- **On Premise**: We manage SAN, 20 Physical Hosts and VMs running on them, Switches, Firewall, VM Creation etc.
- **Monitoring Side**: Zabbix installed and Configured by DBA's which monitors Linux and Windows machine over On-premise, Azure and Google Cloud, we have other monitoring systems also in place.

This gives a brief idea of what all we work on. We have gone through many discussion for this and can't come up with a team name which is liked by both the teams and **recognized in industry** and **suites our work**.

Since this will be our future designations what could be the best suited name for the team?

Edit: If both Engineer and Database comes in single title then both team can agree on that name.

Comment: It is clear that any name that includes "Database" is unsuitable given the breadth of responsibilities. Also, a team name is not just the individual title names with 's' at the end. I'd settle for a TEAM name that gives the most meaning to the organisation, and have TITLE names that are most meaningful for the locale each person works in.

Comment: Are you asking about the team name or the name of an individual title?

Comment: Related: [How do I choose an appropriate job title?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/how-do-i-choose-an-appropriate-job-title)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can name the team any way you want. There is no general rule, as you are already aware of.

---

As supporting arguments, here are some of my answers:

[Answer 1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/138441/98881)

[Answer 2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/130130/98881)

And an answer from another user (@bethlakshmi):

[Answer 3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/22179/98881)

---

In **`Peopleware. Productive Projects and Teams`**, chapter 19, Tom DeMarco and Timothy Lister talk about an unusual team:

> [...] Thus was born the legendary **Black Team**.

> **The Black Team** was initially made up of people who had
> proved themselves to be slightly better at testing than their peers.
> They were slightly more motivated. They also were testing code
> that had been written by someone else, so they were free of the cognitive
> dissonance that hampers developers when testing their own
> programs. [...]

> To enhance the growing image of nastiness, team members
> began to dress in **black** (hence the name **Black Team**). [...] Some of the members grew long mustaches that they could twirl in Simon Legree fashion.

> [...] Programmers began to mutter about the diseased minds on the **Black
> Team**.

> Needless to say, the company was delighted. Every defect the
> team found was one that the customers wouldn't find. The team
> was a success. [...]

As you can see, there is nothing about testing in the team's name.

Comment: Aren't all those answers talking about title names. Also the OP wants to know what to call their team. Not if it's possible to name it whatever they want.

Comment: It is about names in a business / corporation. For a person, for a team, for a department, for a project etc. The same rule applies: the names are not standard anywhere. BTW, how is a title name radically different than a team name?

Comment: Team names are different, because a team may be composed of people with different titles. Just cause the team is called X, doesn't mean the titles are Junior X, and Senior X. Anyway, the question is: "Since this will be our future designations what could be the best suited name for the team?" Your answer is: "Anything". I'm going to assume that "Cheesecake Eaters" is a good name for the team then?

Comment: As an extreme (even if jokingly), a team's name can actually be "Cheesecake Eaters" - provided they are not lactose intolerant. The ONLY rule is that the name MUST BE UNIQUE within the company - to be able to differentiate the teams. Of course, a name related to the job is better, but not vital.

Comment: How about we just number each team, starting at team 0? If you think this is a viable solution, I really don't know how to continue this discussion.

Comment: In many companies, teams also have encoded ID's (numbers of alpha-numeric codes). While the name can change, the code will remain the same. People in the companies also have numbers assigned. Maybe starting from 1000 or 10.000, but that is less relevant. Example: My group's code in the company used to be 3D700009 (I moved to a different group in the meanwhile, and I did not yet learn the number.). Also: remember that people have numbers even when not inside companies: passport numbers, social security numbers...

Comment: Yes, but as humans, we suck at remembering numbers, and prefer something meaningful. Hence the question. Your "Team Black" example works because they are unique. This may be a cultural thing, but if a team called themselves "team black" here most people would instead call them "wankers".

Comment: I will not deny, you are right: some names are better than others. The problem appears when the work is hindered ONLY because they cannot choose between **Engineer** and **Database**. That's when anything is better than nothing, just to "break the deadlock". And a team's name can always change. I worked in a company where managers' best activity was to change the names of the teams, roles and projects, at least once a year. From at least 6 or 7 names of my department, I can only remember 2 acronyms, and the meaning of only 1 acronym. It was useless info, the work was the same.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is most suitable is **Global Operations Team**.

Pick a suitable title for members for Europe and India, and give each member of the team a choice to use either one. Make sure they are aware that they are equivalent.